# How to calculate implied correlation via observed market price (Margrabe option)

Tags: black-scholes, correlation, european-options, implied, nonlinear

I can't seem to figure out how to do the following: compute the implied correlation $ρ_{imp}$ by using the observed market price $M_{quote}$ of a Margrabe option, and solving the non-linear equation shown below:

$$M_{quote} = e^{−q_0T}\times S_0(0)\times N(d_+)−e^{−q_1T}\times S_1(0)\times N(d_−)$$

where:

$$\begin{align}
& d_\pm = \frac{\log\frac{S_0(0)}{S_1(0)}+(q_1 − q_0 ±σ^2/2)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}
\\[4pt]
& \sigma = \sqrt{\sigma^2_0 + \sigma^2_1 − 2\rho_{imp}\sigma_0 \sigma_1}
\end{align}$$

Note that $d_− = d_+ − σ\sqrt{T}$.

Comment: Bear in mind that what you're calculating is the *margrabe option implied correlation*, it's not necessarily the correct correlation to use for pricing other options, it's important to be aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\rho\triangleq\rho_{imp}$. Note that:
$$\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \rho}(\rho)=-\frac{\sigma_0\sigma_1}{\sigma(\rho)}<0$$
Therefore $\sigma$ is monotonic in implied correlation. In addition, the Margrabe pricing function $M(\cdot)$ is also monotonic in volatility $\sigma$ thus you can find an unique solution to the equation:
$$\tag{1}M_{\text{quote}}=M(\rho)$$
where:
$$M(\rho)=e^{−q_0T}S_0(0)N(d_+)−e^{−q_1T}S_1(0)N(d_−)$$
and $d_\pm$ as defined in your question, with $M_{\text{quote}}$ the observed market price. In practice, this can be restated as:
$$\begin{align}
&\min_\rho\left(M(\rho)-M_{\text{quote}}\right)^2\tag{2}
\\
&\ \text{s.t. } \rho \in [-1,1]
\end{align}$$
because $(M(\rho)-M_{\text{quote}})^2\geq0$. This is an optimization problem which can be solved through traditional techniques:

- The solution suggested by @Alex C will give you a quick, approximate answer;
- If you want arbitrary precision, you can use a simple [Newton algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) on either $(1)$ or $(2)$ with root value $\rho=0$, this is quick to program in Excel VBA, or you can maybe even find an online tool that does it. This [PDF](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/statistics_c183_c283/statc183c283_implied_volatility.pdf) explains the method for a vanilla call in a Black-Scholes framework to find the implied volatility, but the set-up is very similar. Another alternative is [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) but this would probably take longer to program and you have to do it on $(2)$;
- You can also use [Excel's Solver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) to find a solution to $(1)$ directly. I have tried with $S_0(0)=\$101$, $S_1(0)=\$113.5$, $\sigma_0=45\%$, $\sigma_1=37\%$, $T=1\text{ year}$ and $q_0=q_1=0$ and it has worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

We know that $-1\le\rho_{imp}\le 1$ so perhaps the simplest approach is to try the possible values $\rho_{imp}=\{-1,-0.9,-0.8,\cdots,0.8,0.9,+1\}$, to calculate resulting $\sigma$ values, d± values, and $M_{quote}$ values, then see which of these is closest to the observed market price. If desired you can then search a finer grid between two adjacent assumed correlations to pin it down more precisely. It is a manual but relatively simple method.